# Delphi IdHTTP Post on Django-created Form

Tags: django, delphi, http, csrf, indy

I'm posting the login-data from delphi on a django-created-form which runs on my localhost. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnPostClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP: TidHTTP;
  auth: TStringList;
  test,token:string;
begin
  IdHTTP := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP.Request.Accept         :='text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
  IdHTTP.Request.AcceptCharSet  :='iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1';
  IdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding :='deflate, gzip, identity, *;q=0';
  IdHTTP.Request.Connection     :='Keep-Alive';
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentType    :='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

  token := IdHTTP.Get('http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/');
  token := copy(token, AnsiPos('csrfmiddlewaretoken', token) + 28, 32);

  IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  with IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders do
  begin
    AddValue('X-CSRFToken',token);
    Values['COOKIE']:='';
    //if IdHTTP2.CookieManager.CookieCollection.count > 0 then
    //  Add('COOKIE: '+token);
  end;

  try
    auth := TStringList.Create;
    auth.Add('csrfmiddlewaretoken='+ token);
    auth.Add('first_name=' + edtVorname.Text);
    auth.Add('last_name=' + edtName.Text);
    auth.Add('function=' + edtFunction.Text);
    auth.Add('company=' + edtCompany.Text);
    auth.Add('country=' + edtCountry.Text);
    auth.Add('email=' + edtEmail.Text);
    auth.Add('password1=' + edtPassword.Text);
    auth.Add('password2=' + edtPasswordAgain.Text);

    //IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Accept-Language', 'en-EN');
    //IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Referer',
    IdHTTP.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/', auth);
  except
  end;
end;
```

Whenever it gets until the Line with the post

```
 IdHTTP.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/', auth);
```

Im getting the 403 error "Forbidden". My guess is im sending the CSRF-Token wrong
because from the python debugger I see being caught in

```
 if csrf_token is None:
            # No CSRF cookie. For POST requests, we insist on a CSRF cookie,
            # and in this way we can avoid all CSRF attacks, including login
            # CSRF.
            return self._reject(request, REASON_NO_CSRF_COOKIE)
```

But HOW is it supposed to be? How do I need to send this csrf-token?

P.S Well I think the problem was that per default `HandleRedirects` is set to `True` and it gave me the 403. The cookievalue in the latest Django versions is usually called `csrftoken` and not `X-CSRFToken` how I did here.

Comment: inspect traffic with F12 function in your browser (Chrome, IE, ...) and see what's in the cookie. Anyway you'll need to use `TIdCookieManager`

Comment: Why do you "guess"? Read the output inside try/except via "(E as EIdHTTPProtocolException).ErrorMessage" and you will see what the page returns.

Comment: its  a rhetorical "guess" I already wrote that the error im getting is the "403" one. Its also the same im catching in the exception atm.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: TidHTTP creates its own TIdCookieManager if AllowCookies is true and no CookieManager is assigned.

Comment: @Vollmilchbb: did you validate that your token value is valid to begin with? What is the initial value of `token` from the `Get()` before you extract a substring from it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau the initial value from Get() is the complete page in html, then I get the substring which is a 32 character-long csrf-token. Django needs this token in some form in order to accept POST requests. I will post the value of token after get in a second mby it helps.

Comment: It would be useful to see the actual HTML, or at lease the `<form>` portion of it. You have to POST what the HTML actually asks for, so I suspect you missed a required value, or did not parse the HTML correctly.

Comment: You are not submitting a `confirmation_key` value, though one is present in the `<form>`.

Comment: Where is the python expecting to retrieve the `csrf_token` from? You have a debugger, what is the python actually receiving?

Comment: well I don't really succeed at posting because the server gives me the "HTTP/1.0 403 FORBIDDEN" I dont think that this value is the root of the problem, although I will try to post the confirmation_key with my form too.

Comment: What is the content of the ErrorMessage? Why don't you inspect traffic from browser as mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set cookie by yourself. When Django response with a form and django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware is in your list of middleware classes (more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/), it should already set csrftoken cookie. So you only have to read value of this cookie and set it to csrfmiddlewaretoken form field.

Also don't forget to set UserAgent in your request. Without UserAgent Indy (Delphi 2010) and Django 1.8 won't cooperate with each other.

I don't know how to add csrfmiddlewaretoken field on redirects so I did it without redirects!

Here is my code:

```
uses
  IdURI, IdCookie;

...

procedure TForm1.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  idHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  token: AnsiString;
  stream: TStringStream;
  params: TStringList;
  cookie: TidCookieRFC2109;
begin
  idHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  stream := TStringStream.Create;
  params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    idHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
    idHTTP.HandleRedirects := False;
    //even if HandleRedirects := False, you must have OnRedirect event (don't know why)
    idHTTP.OnRedirect := IdHttpOnRedirect;
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept         := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptCharSet  := 'iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, sdch';
    IdHTTP.Request.Connection     := 'Keep-Alive';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType    := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    idHTTP.Request.UserAgent      := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36';
    idHTTP.Request.CharSet        := 'utf-8';

    idHTTP.Get('http://www.ttaksa.si/login/');

    cookie := idHTTP.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookie['csrftoken', '.www.ttaksa.si'];
    token := cookie.Value;

    params.Values['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] := token;
    params.Values['username'] := txtUporabniskoIme.Text;
    params.Values['password'] := txtGeslo.Text;

    idHTTP.Post('http://www.ttaksa.si/login/', params, stream);

    idHTTP.Get('http://www.ttaksa.si/objekti/export/?zacetni_datum=23.7.2015-12:00:00&format=xml&indent=2', stream);

    stream.SaveToFile(txtFilename.Text);
    wbUvoz.Navigate('File://' + txtFilename.Text);
  finally
    idHTTP.Free;
    stream.Free;
    params.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTPOnRedirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string;
  var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: boolean; var VMethod: TIdHTTPMethod);
begin
  Handled := True;
end;
```